# converting Json data to c# understandable format

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to convert my json data to `c sharp` understandable format so that I can use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to convert that data to JSON format and send it over HTTP protocol. My json data is as follows:

```
 {
    "m2m:ae":
    {
     "api": "ADN_AE_ATCARD06",
     "rr": "true",
     "lbl": ["AT06"],
     "rn": " adn-ae_AT06" 
   }
 }
```

I tried to write it in `c sharp` understandable format but was able to do this:

```
 var obj = new
            {
               m2m = new
                {
                    api = "ADN_AE45",
                    rr = "true",
                    lbl = new[] { "ad" },
                    rn = "adfrt"

                }
            };
            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
```

my issue is how to include `m2m:ae` into my `c-sharp code`. I am new to json, I am able to convert only if parent object has no value but if it has value I am not able to. please help.

Comment: Typing `json to c#` into your favourite search engine will give you [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) which will show you exactly how. This is basic research,

Comment: @Equalsk There is  tool for that in Visual Studio, _**"Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes"**_.

Comment: @SeM Yes, I know that, my point was rather than OP had done absolutely no research. That option is only available in certain versions of Visual Studio and only on certain frameworks, none of which OP mentions.

Comment: @Equalsk i did research was going through these sites `http://www.objgen.com/json` ,`https://onlinejsontools.com/convert-json-to-text` from here i make out the above code `https://dzone.com/articles/quickly-create-json-object`

Comment: my point is why go for classes when there is this way ..mentioned above

Comment: m2m is the name of the property of your root object.  var would be replaced with your public class object.

Comment: This isn't valid json so there's no way to convert it using normal json deserialization techniques.  The m2m:ae is an invalid property name.

Comment: @Fran this json code i have tried earlier sending through `Postman` and it worked .sending it programatically specifically `m2m:ae:{` creating problem how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was incorrect in my comment.  While "m2m:ae" is not a valid name for a C# property is valid JSON. This can be accomplished by tagging the class property with JsonProperty.

Define your class like this

```
public class TestJson
{
    [JsonProperty("m2m:ae")]
    public Class2 Class2Instance { get; set; }    

}

public class Class2
{
    public string Api { get; set; }
    public string Rr { get; set; }
    public string[] Lbl { get; set; }

    public string Rn { get; set; }
}
```

and then populate your class like this

```
            _sut = new TestJson
            {
                Class2Instance = new Class2 {Api = "ADN_AE45", Rr = "true", Lbl = new[] {"ad"}, Rn = "adfrt"}
            };
```

and serialize

```
            _result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_sut, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            });
```

The resulting serialized object looks like

```
{
  "m2m:ae": {
    "api": "ADN_AE45",
    "rr": "true",
    "lbl": ["ad"],
    "rn": "adfrt"
  }
}
```

and deserialization is the reverse

```
            var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestJson>(_result, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you write the Json in a text file?
If yeah so fileTxt is what is written on the file(as json)

```
String fileTxt = File.ReadAllText(Give a path for a file); //read from file
Jobject Json = Jobject.Parse(fileTxt);   //convert the string to Json
Console.WriteLine($"rr: {Json["rr"]} ");  // get the rr from json and print it
```

Comment: no i haven't i tried sending this `json` code to my local server through `Postman` application.on success now i am trying to send it programatically.but in programme i have to write in such a format which `c#` can understand and covert it into `json` while sending to server.i am only struck at `m2m:ae :{` part how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Other than class method mentioned by Fran one can use the `Dictionary method` to create key value pair and `newtonsoft.json` library to convert to json.

```
var sub= Dictionary<string,string>
{{"abc","xyz"}
};
var main = Dictionary<string,object>
{{"wer:asd",sub}
};
string str= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(main);
```